# How to properly add divs inside another div so the original design doesn't break?

Tags: html, css

I have a this basic HTML:

```
<div id="views-container">
    <div id="html-container"></div>
    <div id="original-page-container"></div>
    <div id="result-page-container"></div>
</div>
```

This is the css for those divs:

```
#views-container > div{
    height:90%;
    width:33%;
    display:inline-block;
}

#html-container{
    background-color: pink;
}

#original-page-container{
    background-color: yellow;
}

#result-page-container{
    background-color: gray;
}
```

This is the final output:

[image]

But then I want to add two divs inside

> html-container

, like this:

```
<div id="views-container">
    <div id="html-container">
        <div id="html-content-area">
            <textarea id="OutputHTML"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="html-info-area">
            bla bla bla
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

when I do this, this is how the page is rendered.

[image]

I want the textarea inside **html-content-area** 
to use all width and heigth from **html-container**.
Later, i will need to hide **html-content-area**  in order
to show something in **html-info-area**.

How could I add those divs inside html-content-area
so they don't break the original design?

I pasted the code in fiddle:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/eyCbB/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: #OutputHTML {position:relative;width:100%}

Comment: The width of divs will be 100% of the parent container by default. If the height of a nested div is to be declared a percentage, it's parent container must have a specified height (unless all containers use percentages all the way up to both `html` and `body`, in which these then must be given a specified height in percentage, pixels, or em's).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you were looking for this

I have made some changes in your fiddle.

```
#views-container > div{
    height:90%;
    width:32%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
html,body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#views-container {
    height:100%;
}
```

Have a look [http://fiddle.jshell.net/eyCbB/1/](http://fiddle.jshell.net/eyCbB/3/)